# I want to use the redis cache in Django, but I found that python 3.7 does not support django-redis. Is there an alternative?

Tags: python, django

I want to use the redis cache in django, but I found that python3.7 does not support django-redis. Is there an alternative? Thanks

Comment: http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/

Comment: funny - https://pypi.org/project/django-redis/ lists python 3.7

Comment: But I will make mistakes when I use it, I am sure that my configuration and code are ok.